# How to initialise AmazonSNSClientBuilder from Spring XML

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can someone pls advise how the new AWS AmazonSNSClient could be constructed using Spring XML?
With the old version of the SDK, we've been using the below code:

```
<spring:bean class="com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient">
<spring:constructor-arg>
    <spring:bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <spring:constructor-arg value="${aws.access.key}" />
        <spring:constructor-arg value="${aws.secret.key}" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:constructor-arg>
```

But the AmazonSNSClient(AWSCredentials awsCredentials) constructor has been deprecated in the new version of the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html).

With the new version the AmazonSNSClientBuilder should be used and the the java code looks like this:

```
 String ec2_region = instanceInfo.getRegion();
  snsClient =
      AmazonSNSClient.builder()
          .withCredentials(iamCredential.getAwsCredentialProvider())
          .withRegion(ec2_region)
          .build();
```

Can you pls advise how this could be done via the Spring XML?